# How to make a group with condition (Python Pandas) without for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a dataframe like below :

```
id_ = ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']
days = [1,10,20,25,100,10,20,30,50]
event = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
df= pd.DataFrame({'id':id_,'days':days,'event':event})
```

Input:

```
  id  days  event
0  A     1      0
1  A    10      0
2  A    20      0
3  A    25      1
4  A   100      0
5  B    10      0
6  B    20      0
7  B    30      1
8  B    50      0
```

I want to make a group around event = 1 :

I want to group the rows within 30 days of the row with event = 1, per id.

I expect the output below (without for loop):

```
  id  days  event  group
0  A     1      0    1.0
1  A    10      0    1.0
2  A    20      0    1.0
3  A    25      1    1.0
4  A   100      0    NaN
5  B    10      0    2.0
6  B    20      0    2.0
7  B    30      1    2.0
8  B    50      0    2.0
```

Comment: Your second NaN should be 2 as it's less than 30 days away from day 30 (or I misunderstood the logic, in any case you can clarify your question breaking down the calculations)

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one event per id?

Comment: @Corralien Yes, I think solution of previous solution works only we have 1 event per id. I want to treat the case like more than one event per id

Comment: Imagine you have (B, 70, 1), what should be the group of (B, 50, 0)? 2 or 3?

Comment: In that case, simply I will exclude this event from our study. Actually, I want to study the case of event, which exist uniquely += 30 days aroud it.

Comment: Can you please comment on the second NaN? Is it a mistake? If not, why it is NaN but not the first 2 rows of A?

Comment: @mozway my criteria is just 30 days around event. So, days of first two rows are 1 and 10 => (25-1) < 30 and (25-10) < 30

Comment: OK, but row index 5 has day 10, event B is day 30: (30-10) = 20 < 30, it should be 2 not NaN. In which case, my solution should work

Comment: @mozway yes you are right for that. sorry for mistake

Comment: OK, I updated your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df['group'] = (pd.merge_asof(
                df.reset_index().sort_values(by='days'),
                df[df['event'].eq(1)].sort_values(by='days'),
                by='id', on='days',
                direction='nearest', tolerance=29)
                 .set_index('index')['event_y']
              )
df['group'] *= pd.factorize(df['id'])[0]+1
```

Output:

```
  id  days  event  group
0  A     1      0    1.0
1  A    10      0    1.0
2  A    20      0    1.0
3  A    25      1    1.0
4  A   100      0    NaN
5  B    10      0    2.0
6  B    20      0    2.0
7  B    30      1    2.0
8  B    50      0    2.0
```